# How to add as many JPanel to a JFrame as specified?

Tags: java, swing

I am using a grid layout but the panels won't display in the frame except the first panel. How do I fix this?

Here is some code

```
int numPanel = 5;

frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(numPanel, 1));

JPanel _panel = new JPanel();

for(int i = 0; i < numPanel; i++)
  {
     frame.add(_panel);
  }
```

The ultimate aim is to have the user specify how many panels to include in the frame. I already know how to get that part done. I just need help with getting panels to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, you're only adding one...

```
JPanel _panel = new JPanel();    
for(int i = 0; i < numPanel; i++)
{
    frame.add(_panel);
}
```

Basically, a component can only reside on a single parent, but all you've done is create a single instance of the `JPanel` and tried to repeatedly add it to the some frame...

Instead, you need to create a new instance on each iteration

```
for(int i = 0; i < numPanel; i++)
{
    JPanel _panel = new JPanel();    
    frame.add(_panel);
}
```

Additionally, if you want to keep a reference to each panel you create, you can either use an array or a `List`

Comment: I can't believe I did not notice that. Hahaha. Thank you!

Comment: @user2840682 Welcome to my world ;)